# bootstrap and angular 2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I'm starting a new (my first) angular 2 app.  I want to use bootstrap.  I see there are at least 2 projects that bring 'native' bootstrap into Angular?

What is wrong with just declaring the bootstrap JS/CSS sources in my `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Some JS/CSS you can use without "2 projects that bring 'native' bootstrap into Angular". But you don't understand that it's not just simply JS/CSS but a component framework that you can use with Angular 2.

> [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) contains all core (and not only) Bootstrap components powered by Angular 2. So **you don't need to include original JS components**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using http://ionicframework.com/, which I begin to learn and it's absolute amazing and has the same functionnality as Bootstrap.